# Itunes won't play .m4a or m4r tones

Tags: itunes, ringtones

Windows 10.  iTunes 12.7.0.166.

I followed the directions found everywhere to create a new aac file less than 30 seconds long and rename it to .m4r  then removing original (newly created) file from library.  When dbl clicking the new .m4r file iTunes launches but nothing happens.  I noticed that I have this same behavior with files already in my Tones folder which are a mixture of .m4r and m4a files.

The files play fine in other players such as groove.

It appears that I am now unable to import custom ringtones.  Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes 12.7, the ringtones functionality has changed. You can still copy custom ringtones to your iOS devices using [this guide from OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2017/09/18/copy-ringtones-to-ios-device-with-itunes-127/), or [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207955).

If you still need access to the features in previous versions of iTunes, Apple made iTunes 12.6.3 available for cases like this: [Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT208079)

Check out this Apple Support document for more information on the iTunes 12.7 update: [Changes in the new iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208075)

Comment: Note: If you've already been using 12.7 you may need to have a backup of your previous Library to be able to seamlessly revert to 12.6.3. It's claimed it will import, but I found it wouldn't.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help.  When I drag the ringtone into/onto the iTunes app running on my desktop nothing happens.  It doesn't show in tones under the device and it doesn't show under songs anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use iTunes 12.7 to add ringtones to your iPhone, then you can try some iTunes alternatives, here is a video tutorial, hope it works for you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sl94Nj0gvhM&feature=youtu.be